# How can I get the width of ExpandableListView's group indicator drawable on Android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indicator

If I use the default group indicator (not setting a new one), how can I know the padding width for the layout of groupview?

So can let my layout won't overlap with the group indicator.

Is that possible? Because I can't find a method to getGroupIndicator.
Or I must have to set a new one that I know its size.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the attribute here:

```
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
```

Comment: is this possible to add programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use reflection:

```
Field field_mIndicatorRight = listView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mIndicatorRight");
field_mIndicatorRight.setAccessible(true);
int mIndicatorRight = (Integer) field_mIndicatorRight.get(listView);
```